# stateProvider - controller property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am trying to putt a value in the controller property through a function.
Doing something like this:

```
.state('integrator.optionCommandTabContent', {
    url: '/integrator/optionCommandTabContent/:optionId/:ctrlName',
    views: {
        'optionConfigTabContent@': {
            templateUrl: '../../../angular-app/components/integrator/integrator-conf/option-conf/commands-tab/command-tab.html',
            controller: function ($stateParams){                            
                return $stateParams.ctrlName.toString();                           
            },
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            resolve: {
                optionId: function($stateParams){
                    return $stateParams.optionId;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It seems like the controller property don't get the return value of the function. Is it possible to do something like this but in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *`controller`* should not return anything. It should provide actions and do some init and destroy stuff only. E.g.

```
controller: function ($stateParams, $scope, someService){    
     // naive sync init
     this.items = someService.load($sateParams.id);
     // example of action
     this.edit = function(item) {
        ...
     }
     // destroy on view leave
     $scope.$on('$on', function(){
        ...
     });
},
```

and that could be consumed int your view

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items"> ...
<button ng-click="ctrl.edit(item) ...
```